# Split agenda Day view in full calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I would like to set the agendaDay view to look like this :[image]

So it will matches the page width and remove the need to scroll, i wonder if maybe there is a build in function in full calendar to do so

Here are my setting:

```
header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
```

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/vggyknpL/)

Comment: Not that I know of. You'd have to create a completely custom view. FullCalendar uses quite fixed layouts to ensure a consistent look, it doesn't alter the layout based on screen width (only the width of the pre-determined columns) https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/

Comment: thanks.. i guess there is no other way than completely do it from scratch...